# Spring security get Wrong Principal in Concurrency Environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

In my micro service, I have a `ResourceServer` and an `AuthServer` at port 19000.

In `ResourceServer` here is the part of the application.yml

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      id: gateway
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:19000/user
      prefer-token-info: false
```

the /user end point is simple like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/user")
    public Principal getUser(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

and I will get UserDetail in the ResourceServer , use this code

```
void me(Principal principal) {
    String name = principal.getName();    
}
```

At the beginning ,the `name`  is always the right name . but If userA and userB access the interface with their token at the almost same time, Things go wrong. Sometimes I will get userA's name when I except userB' name.

I check out the spring security source code , In `UserInfoTokenServices.java` , I found this code probably cause the mistake. When many querys come in, they multi-threads operate the same `this.restTemplate` , and the logical of accessToken and existingToken , when they equals, but other thread maybe will change the `this.restTemplate` before it calls `restTemplate.getForEntity`

```
private Map<String, Object> getMap(String path, String accessToken) {
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("Getting user info from: " + path);
        }
        try {
            OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate = this.restTemplate;
            if (restTemplate == null) {
                BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource = new BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails();
                resource.setClientId(this.clientId);
                restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource);
            }
            OAuth2AccessToken existingToken = restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext()
                    .getAccessToken();
            if (existingToken == null || !accessToken.equals(existingToken.getValue())) {
                DefaultOAuth2AccessToken token = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(
                        accessToken);
                token.setTokenType(this.tokenType);
                restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().setAccessToken(token);
            }
            return restTemplate.getForEntity(path, Map.class).getBody();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            this.logger.warn("Could not fetch user details: " + ex.getClass() + ", "
                    + ex.getMessage());
            return Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap("error",
                    "Could not fetch user details");
        }
    }
}
```

I think this will cause the wrong Principal info.

And In fact. When I use this code

```
Principal principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String name = principal.getName();
```

the `name` will suddenly go wrong ,then next time be right again.

Are you guys ever confused with this situation?

What to do I can get the right username all the time.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `this.restTemplate` changes as it has already been copied to the stack / local variable it will not change to another instance because the local reference in a separate thread because another changed it (when the same instance change this can happen!). Next to that the `RestTemplate` itself is thread safe. However what you should, ideally do, is create a `UserInfoTokenServices` instance with no default `rest template` that way each thread has its own instance. I suspect you are creating an instance with a pre-defined `RestTemplate`.

Comment: there is only one instance of UserInfoTokenServices and 1 instance of OAuth2RestTemplate.

Comment: As stated, configure it without an explicit template (or make it request scoped).

Comment: I think the `restTemplate` has be shared in multi-thread

Comment: No it shouldn't... because, as you noticed, it will change stuff on the client. Hence you want each thread to have its own copy... At let the the `OAuth2ClientContext` should be request or session scoped and not a singleton. Basically you will need to scope the stuff that changes on a request basis.

Comment: the UserInfoTokenServices.java is from org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource , and how can I change it , is this a bug of Spring security?

Answer (score 0):

when server started,
step 1 if there is not a bean of AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.class , will goto step 2

step 2: if there is not a bean of ResourceServerTokenServices.class
,run the code below:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ResourceServerTokenServices.class)
public UserInfoTokenServices userInfoTokenServices() {
    UserInfoTokenServices services = new UserInfoTokenServices(
            this.sso.getUserInfoUri(), this.sso.getClientId());
    services.setRestTemplate(this.restTemplate);
    services.setTokenType(this.sso.getTokenType());
    if (this.authoritiesExtractor != null) {
        services.setAuthoritiesExtractor(this.authoritiesExtractor);
    }
    if (this.principalExtractor != null) {
        services.setPrincipalExtractor(this.principalExtractor);
    }
    return services;
}
```

so ResourceServerTokenServices is singleton, and so its `restTemplate`,

when program run into this code below , multi-thread will concurrent operate `restTemplate`. Something wrong will come out.

```
 private Map<String, Object> getMap(String path, String accessToken) {
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("Getting user info from: " + path);
        }
        try {
            OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate = this.restTemplate;
            if (restTemplate == null) {
                BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource = new BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails();
                resource.setClientId(this.clientId);
                restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource);
            }
            OAuth2AccessToken existingToken = restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext()
                    .getAccessToken();
            if (existingToken == null || !accessToken.equals(existingToken.getValue())) {
                DefaultOAuth2AccessToken token = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(
                        accessToken);
                token.setTokenType(this.tokenType);
                restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().setAccessToken(token);
            }
            return restTemplate.getForEntity(path, Map.class).getBody();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            this.logger.warn("Could not fetch user details: " + ex.getClass() + ", "
                    + ex.getMessage());
            return Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap("error",
                    "Could not fetch user details");
        }
    }
```

the right way is : If ResourceServer there is no AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration, you'd better provide an implement of ResourceServerTokenServices.class. This will be controlled better.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem: concurrent requests mashed up principals.

Today applied advice from this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-authentication-with-reddit .

1) Added `@EnableOAuth2Client` annotation,

2) Added `OAuth2ClientContext clientContext` to rest remplate.

Me final RestTemplate bean looks this way:

```java
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate(UserInfoTokenServices remoteTokenServices,
                                             OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setClientId(securityProperties.getServiceClientId());
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret(securityProperties.getServiceClientSecret());
        OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);
        remoteTokenServices.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

And my tests show that bug has gone and no mash happens in principals.